# Runtime error for n

Tags: c++, arrays, string, vector

when i take input as:

8

10,4,74,61,8,37,2,35

i get runtime error.but if i remove 8 from input and cin>>n from code the code is working perfect .
How can i take n also as input?
example link "https://ideone.com/hr96ef"

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int n;
cin>>n;
std::string input_str;
std::vector<int> vect;

std::getline( std::cin, input_str );

std::stringstream ss(input_str);

 int i;

while (ss >> i)
{
  vect.push_back(i);

  if (ss.peek() == ',')
  ss.ignore();
}
cout<<vect[3];
return 0;
}
```

Comment: After the call to `std::getline` look at the contents of `input_str` to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: I update the question,added link to example code please check

Comment: use std::istringstream ss( input_str ); instead

Comment: thank you  cin.ignore(); solved the problem